# Login failed when running Liquibase to connect and update Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure, jdbc

We use liquibase(Java) to run in Azure pipeline to update the SQL databases on a newly deployed Azure SQL server, the update always fails with the following error, even though the account used can login to SSMS without problem.

```
Liquibase Update Failed: Login failed for user 'useraccount'..  For more information, use the --logLevel flag)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2730984Z      [exec] May 07, 2020 2:04:15 PM liquibase.logging.jvm.JavaUtilLogger info
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2732159Z      [exec] INFO: Login failed for user 'useraccount'.
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2732665Z      [exec] liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'useraccount'.
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2743042Z      [exec]    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:88)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2769292Z      [exec]    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:603)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2770567Z      [exec]    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:110)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2771290Z      [exec] Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'devops-shr'.
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2771866Z      [exec]    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2772443Z      [exec]    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2773654Z      [exec]    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2774188Z      [exec]    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2529)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2774736Z      [exec]    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1905)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2775303Z      [exec]    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2775883Z      [exec]    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1893)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2776417Z      [exec]    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2776961Z      [exec]    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2778859Z      [exec]    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1045)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2779577Z      [exec]    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2780096Z      [exec]    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2780636Z      [exec]    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
2020-05-07T14:04:15.2781165Z      [exec]    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:79)
```

Comment: There is a code format option in the editor - please use it - your question is currently unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when trying to use the `liquibase` CLI tool and the `generateChangeLog` functionality.

I found the root cause by temporarily [enabling Audit Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview) for the SQL Server inside Azure and taking a look at the database events:

`DATABASE AUTHENTICATION FAILED` with the payload `Error 18456 State 65`. [Indicating](https://zarez.net/?p=44) that the password did not match for the user.

The password for my technical users had some special characters that (somehow?) don't get escaped when referring them from the `liquibase.properties` file.

For a quick validation, I configured the username + password inline using the Liquibase Maven Plugin inside the `pom.xml` and escaped the characters there (IntelliJ auto-suggest what needs to be escaped):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <changeLogFile>changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
    <outputChangeLogFile>changelog.mssql.sql</outputChangeLogFile>
    <defaultSchemaName>test</defaultSchemaName>
    <url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=db</url>
    <username>user@xyz.database.windows.net</username>
    <password>SUPER_SECRETWITH_SPECIAL_CHARACTER&amp;</password>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

... and can then use Liquibase via the Maven Plugin:

```
mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message is *intentionally* vague.  SQL Server will not tell you why the login failed because you are an authenticated and untrusted client.

The Server Error Logs or Extended Events will tell you more.  The two most common errors are that the password was incorrect, or that the user was unable to access the database specified in the connection string.

Comment: I used exact the same user name and password logging to SSMS successfully. This is a sa account, so I don't think there is any permission issue. The same script works on an Azure SQL server that we setup a few years ago. The Liquibase version is old. Could it possible that the new Azure SQL server is not compatible with the old JDBC driver? Or something needs to be added to the connection string to be compatible?